# Cast 2 decimal values only if currency is not 0.0000

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-when

I'm trying to print

**Condition 1**: If currency appears as 0.00, then remove the decimal points (.00)

```
Ex: 0.00 -> 0
```

**Condition 2**: If currency appears as greater than 0.00, then keep the decimal places to 2 places (so, ######.00)

```
12.46 -> 12.46 
0.00 -> 0
13.96 -> 13.96
```

I have tried the following but the CAST will not work:

```
CASE 
WHEN CAST([Money] AS NUMERIC(10,2)) = 0.00 THEN CAST([Money] AS INT)
ELSE CAST([Money] AS NUMERIC(10,2)) END BankPile,
```

Comment: There is no way to do this -- it depends on the user agent.  You can cast to a string Gordon suggests, but the real way to solve this problem is to leverage how your front end displays the data.

Comment: @Hogan Good point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you care about such details, then you need to cast the result as a stirng:

```
(case when CAST([Money] AS NUMERIC(10,2)) = 0.00 then '0'
      else cast(cast([Money] as numeric(10, 2)) as varchar(255))
 end)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a column that contains both decimal and integer types. I'd recommend just returning decimal values and setting the format in the display layer (form, report, web page, etc.)